# PHP function HTML output shows in browser but not the Javascript innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a PHP function that queries a MySQL database and outputs an html table. This works fine with following PHP code:

```
<?php
showTable();
?>
```

But if I use the javascript code:

```
form.onsubmit = function() {
    document.getElementById("php_code").innerHTML="<?PHP showTable(); ?>";
};
```

the browser does not show the table. There seems to be a problem with the (innerHTML) html string. I noticed for example that a carriage return inside a MySQL parameter causes problem with the innerHTML, but not with the PHP-only code.

Is there a way to fix this?

(the reason I wish to use the javascript bit is to be able to have a form with two buttons with different PHP functions depending on the form buttons clicked).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the output of showTable() properly if you want to do it in a variable like that.

However, I propose a different method for you. Include the HTML like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="showTable">
    <?php showTable(); ?>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
form.onsubmit = function() {
    document.getElementById("php_code").innerHTML= document.getElementById('showTable').innerHTML;
};
</script>
```

Notice the use of type="text/html" in the previous script tag. This will cause the table not to be shown to the browser, but retrievable by javascript.

Good luck.

Comment: cool... but what if the output of `showTable()` includes a `<script>...</script>` block?

Comment: @Lee then this would probably fail. That's a valid point. However, seems like a function called showTable() shouldn't really be outputting any javascript :)
@tucson you're welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Php runs on the *server*, it generates the html page, and returns it to the browser for rendering.  Javascript runs in the *browser* -- which happens **after** the php has finished running.  It is not possible to invoke a php function directly from within a javascript function.

In order to do what you're trying to do, you'll need to move your php code into its own PHP file, and use something like [jQuery's `load()` function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to invoke your php via a separate http request.  Something like this:

```
form.onsubmit = function() {
    jQuery("#php_code").load('show_table.php');
};
```

where "show_table.php" contained something like this:

```
<?php 
    /** remember to include the function showTable()
     * here, so you can call it below.
     */
    function showTable() {
      /* your function source here */
    }

    showTable();
```

Hope this helps.  You might also want to do some research on web applications in general -- specifically, read up on the *roles* that are played by PHP and Javascript respectively.

---

**edit**

If you understand the distinction I've outlined above, and your actual intention *really is* to have the php function run *when the page is initially loaded*, rather than waiting till the javascript function is called, then you can modify your code as follows:

```
form.onsubmit = function() {
    document.getElementById("php_code").innerHTML="<?PHP echo(addcslashes(showTable(), "\0..\37\\'\"/\177..\377")); ?>";
};
```

In order to use this approach, you will also need to make your function `showTable()` *return* the string rather than printing it out directly.  One way to accomplish this is with [php's output buffering functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.examples.basic.php).  Just take your existing `showTable()` function, and wrap it like this:

```
function showTable() {
   ob_start();

   /* existing showTable logic goes here */

   return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: If the code is in a PHP file and show table spits out some HTML what he does is absolutely valid (and should work).

Comment: I agree, and it will work if he properly escapes it (which can be accomplished using `htmlspecialchars(addcslashes(showTable()))`.  But based on the example he gave, I think it's clear that he's expecting the php function to be executed when/if the javascript handler is invoked -- not unconditionally when the page is loaded.

Comment: for completeness, I've added a second example that shows this alternate approach.  Also note: my comment above was slightly inaccurate - `htmlspecialchars` is not needed in this case.  The correct escaping for use inside a javascript block is shown in the second example above.

Comment: I am not sure why, but I could not get your first proposed solution (with jquery) to work. I'll have to dig deeper into jquery. Thanks anyway for the input. Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem. Sorry it didn't work for you. The method you chose will work too - just be aware of the following: (a) without additional escaping, it will break if `showTable()` prints a `</script>` tag anywhere within its output; and (b) you'll be running `showTable()` every time the page loads, whether the javascript handler runs or not (you can see this using your browser's "View Source" feature). Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

- Be sure that no characters come out of `showTable()` that would interfere with the JavaScript code (like quotes)
- Convert new lines to break characters (`nl2br()`) in your `showTable()` function.